# Transformation of a trigonometric equation to algebraic, replacing $\sin\theta$ with $\xi$

Tags: trigonometry

During reading the book "Nature of Magnetism (Science for Everyone)-Mir Publishers (1985)" (page 173), I encountered a transformation of a trigonometric equation to algebraic one ([scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfofx.png)).

> $$\frac{\partial'\epsilon_{an}}{\partial\theta}\equiv V\mathscr M\left(\frac12\beta\mathscr M\sin{\theta}-H_x\cos\theta+H_z\sin\theta\right)=0\\
> \frac{\partial^2\epsilon_{an}}{\partial\theta^2}\equiv V\mathscr M\left(\beta\mathscr M\cos{\theta}-H_x\sin\theta+H_z\cos\theta\right)>0\tag{3.15}$$
>
> The condition of positiveness of the second derivative singles out among the solutions of equations (3.15) those that correspond to a minimum, not to a maximum. A replacement $\sin\theta=\xi$ transforms equation (3.15) into an algebraic equation of the fourth degree in $\xi$:
>
> $$(\beta\mathscr M\xi-H_x)^2(1-\xi^2)=H_z\xi^2\tag{3.16}$$

V is volume which is constant, M is spontaneous magnetization is also a constant, H is the magnetic field whose H_x and H_z are its components along x and z ; both are constants.ϵ_an is the energy needs to be minimized. \beta is just 1/kT another constant.

They say to simply replace $\sin\theta$ by $\xi$.
Could anyone could give more details? Any hints?

Comment: Even looking at the image, and questions here should not require one to look at a linked image (instead, type in the appropriate equation(s)), does not seem enough context to answer your question. I see $H_x$ and $H_z.$ Are these partial derivatives (with respect to $x$ and $z)$ of $H$? Or constants? Or variables? Or functions? Also, there is a partial derivative with respect to zeta, so I would expect the transformed equation to have a partial derivative with respect to theta, but this is not the case. I also see equality, identity, greater than symbols all used in the "equation".

Comment: The first equation has the form $\frac12p\sin2\theta+q\cos\theta+r\sin\theta=0$. Expand $\sin2\theta$, collect $\cos\theta$ terms on one side and non-$\cos\theta$ terms on the other, factor, square, and rewrite $\cos^2\theta$ in terms of $\sin^2\theta$. (BTW: Equation 3.16 should have $H_z^2$ on the right-hand side.)